# hg .ignore regex - how to allow a new/mod'ed test_<filename>.c to be displayed but not the binary test_<filename>?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I have a set of unit tests in C. Their form is:  `test_<filename>.c` and when compiled they are `test_<filename>`.

I am trying to have new `*.C` file show up when a `hg status` is displayed, but any binary files (`test_<filename>`) to be suppressed.

What I have now is:

```
src/project/test/.+/test_.+[^\.][^c]$
```

this works fine except for one case:  where the `<filename>` ends with a `c` (i.e., `test_func`, from `test_func.c`)

Then test_func is displayed with a status of '? test_func'

I am a moderate regex guy, but have searched for a couple of weeks, but haven't found a solution - which I assume to be easy, once I see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hairy, but it seems to work, using a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) (that's the `(?<!a)b` part):

```
src/project/test/.+/test.+([^c]|(?<!\.)c)$
```

To expand the part I changed — that is, `([^c]|(?<!\.)c)`:

```
(
    [^c]             // the last character can be anything other than c
    |                // or, if it is c
    (?<!\.)c         // it cannot be preceded by .
)
```

The extra `\` in the negative lookbehind ("`c` not preceded by `.`") is needed to escape the `.`, which otherwise means "any character".